# Ignore Calling Argument

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters

Is it possible do *not include an argument conditionally* when calling a function?

### Exemple

Here is a snippet of what behavior I am wanting:

```js
const a=1;
const b="spam";

console.log( a, b!="spam"?b:undefined ); // I would like to ignore b when b=="spam"
// expected output: "1"
// actual output: "1 undefined"
```

### Testings

Here is a snippet representing a logging of every value I have tested so far:

#### Value

```js
const a="a";
const b=0;
const c=NaN;
const d=null;
const e=undefined;
const f=void 0;
const g="g";

console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
// expected output: a 0 NaN null g
// actual output: a 0 NaN null undefined undefined g
```

#### Filter

```js
const variable = null;

let test = [variable].filter(f => f != null).join();

console.log("start");
console.log(); // no output
console.log(test); // output: "" (type: string)
console.log(typeof test); // output: "string"
console.log(); // no output
console.log("end");
```

#### Filter & Apply

```js
const variable=null;

let test = [variable].filter(f => f != variable);

console.log("start");
console.log(test); // output: "(0) []"
console.log.apply(console, test); // no output
console.log.apply(console, null); // no output
console.log("end");
```

### Workaround

That:

```js
const a=1;
const b="spam"

b!="spam"?console.log(a,b):console.log(a);
```

works, but it is **not** ignoring an argument at call, it rather test the variable before to then not include it as an argument

Comment: Ahmm... Just don't log out the values you don't want logged? I am sure I misunderstand your question though.

Comment: You can filter out the `undefined` variables, something like this: `console.log(...[a,b,c,d,e,f,g].filter(o => typeof o !== 'undefined'));`

Comment: The title of the question doesn't really match the code. `console.log` does not ignore arguments, so I'm not sure why you would expect it to ignore undefined arguments. Considering how often `console.log` is used for debugging, it would be horrible if it did.

Comment: try to test my answer bellow

Comment: however, define what you mean by "ignore" if it does not mean "do not include" what should it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an array, filter it of unnecessary values, then use the [spread syntax ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), like this

```js
const a = "a";
const b = 0;
const c = NaN;
const d = null;
const e = undefined;
const f = void 0;
const g = "g";

console.log(...[a, b, c, d, e, f, g].filter((x) => x !== undefined));
```

If you want, you can declare as well your `console.logDefined` function, like this:

```js
console.logDefined = function () {
  console.log(...Array.from(arguments).filter((x) => x !== undefined));
};

const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] = ["a", 0, NaN, null, undefined, void 0, "g"];

console.log(       "console.log array        >>", a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
console.logDefined("console.logDefined array >>", a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
```